# cloud storage: unable to upload any content while local with golang

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have this piece of code:

```
ctx:=context.Background()
    cliente, err := storage.NewClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    clienteCS := cliente.Bucket("prueba123456789")
    w:=clienteCS.Object("prueba").NewWriter(ctx)
    w.ContentType = "text/plain"
    if _, err := w.Write([]byte("abcde\n")); err != nil {
           log.Fatal(err)
    }
    attrs, err := clienteCS.Attrs(ctx)
    fmt.Printf("atrr: %+v   err:%v\n",attrs,err)
```

When I run this program, in the console I can see the attributes printed from my bucket, that would mean for me that there is nothing wrong with the configuration
[image: console]
, but the problem is that when I see on [console.cloud.google.com](http://console.cloud.google.com) I see no file on my bucket [image: my bucket] even on api dashboard does not seem like any api has been called(that peak before the red line is other api I was using) [image: api dashboard], even though no error is showing on my console that could indicate something went wrong

Comment: I see some differences between your code and the one here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage#writing_to_cloud_storage.  Can you provide your full code?

Comment: I just saw the problem, it was just that I didn't close the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just forgot about closing the client, [this page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage#writing_to_cloud_storage) alert this problem, always must close the client or the file won't be send, so just need to add some lines:

```
if err := w.Close(); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
            return
        }
```